# JSON "text" content is preventing script from running

Tags: google-apps-script

Am writing a app script for communication between a telegram bot and a googlesheet. This is written in googleapp scripts. With some help from the Guru's here i was able to get most of it working including the APi connection, webhooks and other relavent functions. Extracting the "text" on the JSON is somehow not working. Ive debugged and found out that the  `var userInput = contents.result[1].date` is causing my script to stop.

1. Telegram user Adds Bot
2. User Keys in a pass (e.g. applegate)
3. script will search for a match on the googlesheet
4. sendMessage will return a success or failure message to the user on telegram

the actual JSON contents from a telegram message from my phone to the bot are as shown, i  typed "Welcome":

```html
var yourJSON = {
      ok: true,
      result: [
        {
          update_id: 11111111,
          message: {
            message_id: 412,
            from: {
              id: 22222222,
              is_bot: false,
              first_name: "don",
              username: "king",
              language_code: "en",
            },
            chat: {
              id: 333333333,
              first_name: "Don",
              username: "king",
              type: "private",
            },
            date: 1600865179,
            text: "Test",
          },
        },
        {
          update_id: 111111111,
          message: {
            message_id: 413,
            from: {
              id: 1111111111,
              is_bot: false,
              first_name: "Don",
              username: "king",
              language_code: "en",
            },
            chat: {
              id: 44444444,
              first_name: "don",
              username: "king",
              type: "private",
            },
            date: 1600865186,
            text: "applegate",
          },
        },
      ],
    };
```

Below is the script that keeps stopping when i pop in  `//var userInput = contents.result[1].date;`

```html
function doPost(e){
    var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var id = contents.message.from.id;
    var username = contents.message.chat.username;
    //var userInput = contents.result[1].date;
    sendMessage(id, username +", " + "Please wait");
    var ssId = "XXXXXXX";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var idArr = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
    idArr = idArr.map(row => row[0]);
    var idIndex = idArr.indexOf(userInput);
         if(idIndex < 0){
                  sendMessage(id, "User not found")
             }else{
        let rowNumber = idIndex + 2;
        let colNumber = 4; //col D
        var dateNow = new Date;
        sheet.getRange(rowNumber, colNumber).setValue(dateNow);
        sendMessage(id, "You have successfully registered");
      
    }
  }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
i found that for some reason var userInput = contents.message.text works to get the text out. but the matching of input and returning success or failure is not working. Here is the code now.

```html
function doPost(e){
    var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var id = contents.message.from.id;
    var username = contents.message.chat.username;
    var userInput = contents.message.text;
    sendMessage(id, username + userInput +", " + "Please wait");
    var ssId = "XXXX";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var idArr = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
    var valueRange = idArr.map(row => row[0]);
    var idIndex = idArr.indexOf(userInput);
         if(userInput == valueRange){
        sendMessage(id, "You have successfully inpro")
        let rowNumber = idIndex + 2;
        let colNumber = 4; //col D
        var dateNow = new Date;
        sheet.getRange(rowNumber, colNumber).setValue(dateNow);
    
             }else{
        
      sendMessage(id, "User not found")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nesting structure of your JSON object `date` is a subobject of `message`

So to access `date` of the second `result` of `yourJSON` you should define

`var userInput = yourJSON.result[1].message.date;`

As for matching input, the problems are

1. In the line `var idIndex = idArr.indexOf(userInput)` - you probably meant `var idIndex = valueRange.indexOf(userInput)`  - `indexOf()` cannot be succesfuly applied to 2D arrays.
2. In the line
   `if(userInput == valueRange)`.

Here you are trying to comprar a single string against a value range containg an array of strings...

Rewrite the end of your function as following:

```js
      var idArr = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
      var valueRange = idArr.map(row => row[0]);
      var idIndex = valueRange.indexOf(userInput);
      if(idIndex > - 1){
        sendMessage(id, "You have successfully inpro");
        let rowNumber = idIndex + 2;
        let colNumber = 4; //col D
        var dateNow = new Date;
        sheet.getRange(rowNumber, colNumber).setValue(dateNow);    
    }else{        
      sendMessage(id, "User not found")
    }
```